# elixir map with mixed keys

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

in the Phoenix application, I have a function that takes two maps, and creates two entries in the database via Ecto.Changeset.

```
def create_user_with_data(user_attrs, data_attrs) do
    name = cond do
        data_attrs["name"] ->
            data_attrs["name"]
        data_attrs[:name] ->
            data_attrs[:name]
        true -> nil
    end
    Ecto.Multi.new()
    |> Ecto.Multi.insert(:user, User.registration_changeset(%User{}, Map.put(user_attrs, :name, name)))
    |> Ecto.Multi.run(:user_data, fn(%{user: user}) ->
        %MyApp.Account.UserData{}
        |> MyApp.Account.UserData.changeset(Map.put(data_attrs, :user_id, user.id))
        |> Repo.insert()
    end)
    |> Repo.transaction()
end
```

because the keys in these map can be both atoms and lines, I have to check these keys.

but the expression

```
Map.put(user_attrs, :name, name)
```

will cause an error

```
** (Ecto.CastError) expected params to be a map with atoms or string keys, got a map with mixed keys: %{:name => "John", "email" => "m@gmail.com"}
```

if the keys are strings.

Is there any best practice in dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd convert all the keys to atoms first and then use atoms everywhere.

```
def key_to_atom(map) do
  Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn
    {key, value}, acc when is_atom(key) -> Map.put(acc, key, value)
    # String.to_existing_atom saves us from overloading the VM by
    # creating too many atoms. It'll always succeed because all the fields
    # in the database already exist as atoms at runtime.
    {key, value}, acc when is_binary(key) -> Map.put(acc, String.to_existing_atom(key), value)
  end)
end
```

Then, convert pass all such maps through this function:

```
user_attrs = user_attrs |> key_to_atom
data_attrs = data_attrs |> key_to_atom
```

Now you can `Map.put` atom keys whenever you want to.

Comment: The potential problem with this is that's an attack vector, as in, if someone where to know, they could overflow the system quite easily by sending random strings through the API, and you would be transforming all of them to atoms. I think it makes more sense to do it the other way around and transform them all to strings, then Ecto ONLY transforms the explicitly required ones to atoms.

Answer (score 10):

Explicitly cast all the keys to strings with [`Kernel.to_string/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#to_string/1):

```
data_attrs = for {k, v} <- data_attrs,
               do: {to_string(k), v}, into: %{}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used this recursive solution. Works great for nested map, and for mixed content (atom and string keys mixed) as well

```
defmodule SomeProject.MapHelper do
  def to_params(map) do
    Enum.map(map, &process_pair/1) |> Enum.into(%{})
  end

  defp process_pair({k, v}) do
    {"#{k}", process_value(v)}
  end

  defp process_value(v) when is_map(v) do
    to_params(v)
  end

  defp process_value(v), do: v
end
```

Here are the tests

```
defmodule CrecerInversiones.MapHelperTest do
  use CrecerInversiones.DataCase
  alias CrecerInversiones.MapHelper

  describe "to_params" do
    test "convert atom keys to strings" do
      params = MapHelper.to_params(%{a: "hi params"})

      assert params == %{"a" => "hi params"}
    end

    test "convert nested maps" do
      params = MapHelper.to_params(%{a: "hi params", b: %{z: "nested map"}})

      assert params == %{"a" => "hi params", "b" => %{"z" => "nested map"}}
    end

    test "accept mixed content" do
      params = MapHelper.to_params(%{"a" => "hi params", "b" => %{z: "nested map"}})

      assert params == %{"a" => "hi params", "b" => %{"z" => "nested map"}}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using string interpolation rather than `Kernal.to_string/1` directly?

Answer (score 0):

@Dogberts solution is great. But if you want to extend it and transform a multidimensional map, you could use some recursion:

```
def map_keys_to_atom(map) when is_map(map) do
  Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn
    {key, value}, acc when is_atom(key) ->
      Map.put(acc, key, map_keys_to_atom(value))

    {key, value}, acc when is_binary(key) ->
      Map.put(acc, String.to_existing_atom(key), map_keys_to_atom(value))
  end)
end

def map_keys_to_atom(map), do: map
```